Selenium Webdriver - how to select element
In this below page excerpt, I need to be able to click 'App Profiles'.
But what ever I try I cannot get it  to work.
I keep getting OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException.
<body>
  <div id="main-page">
    <div class="page"></div>
    <div id="page-header" class="page-header">
      <div id="page-header-navbar" class="page-header-navbar">
        <div class="page-header-contents">
          <div class="page-header-navbar-left">
            <div class="nav-menus">
              <div class="nav-menu" data-item="dashboard">
                <div class="nav-menu-header selected -js-header">
                  <i class="nav-menu-icon fa fa-tachometer"></i>
                  <span class="nav-menu-header-label">Dashboard</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="nav-menu" data-item="policy">
                <div class="nav-menu-header -js-header">
                  <i class="nav-menu-icon fa fa-sitemap"></i>
                  <span class="nav-menu-header-label">App Profiles</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

These have been tried:
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div\[@class='nav-menu-header-label' and text()='App Profiles'\]"));        
IWebElement appProfilesElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span\[text()='App Profiles'\]"));     


Did you try to wait for element to be fully loaded in page?

Try wait first:
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# wait for 10 seconds
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
xpath = "//div[@class='nav-menu-header-label' and text()='App Profiles']"
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
element.click()


Hi Arthur,
thank you for your quick reply.
But unfortunately:
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException' occurred in WebDriver.dll: 'Timed out after 10 seconds'
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait1.Until[TResult](Func2 condition, CancellationToken token)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)

I would debug in two aspects: 1. make sure this item can be clickable; 2. try longer wait time - extend the 10 seconds to 30 seconds

Hey Arthur, as troubleshooting i have started enumerating all elements on the page. And now i see that there is something wrong. So prior to this code i already clicked a link that opens a new TAB. And what i now see is that the code is reporting elements from the first page...... So how do i 'move along' with the new tab?

I'm not sure how you got the XPath, but it does not look correct. Using the same code, I've got the XPath: //*[@id="page-header-navbar"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span
You can simply Open F12 Developer Tools --> Inspect the element --> Locate the element --> Right click on it --> Copy --> Copy XPath.
So it should be: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"page-header-navbar\"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span"));
Now I can get the element without any error message.

Hi Kendrick,
Thank you for the reply.
My issue was that I just not had the Driver 'focus' on the correct TAB.
I then followed the instructions on Selenium to fix this.
But with regards to selecting the element your answer is absolutely correct!
I used the same Inspection but then used --> Copy Element to come up what i'm using, and this is also working. I guess it is a matter of preference.
string xpathExpressionAP = "//span[@class='nav-menu-header-label' and text()='App Profiles']";
IWebElement elementAP2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpathExpressionAP));
elementAP2.Click();

What is not in the code above is a click that opened a new TAB in the browser.
So the issue was that the Selenium driver did not had the reference/focus to the correct TAB. Once I followed the Selenium guidance I could get the reference to the correct element.
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/
